# Retrieve File From IIS Server With Special Character In Name C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, iis, download, escaping

I have a file located at **http://10.1.10.211:8600/CardsPro+.exe**

And I am trying to retrieve it with the following code but get the error 
"**HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found**"

```
    private WebClient webClient;
    private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
    private string tempFile;
    private string md5;
    internal string TempFilePath
    {
        get { return this.tempFile; }
    }
    internal UpdateInfoDownloadForm(Uri location, string md5, Icon programIcon)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (programIcon != null)
        {
            this.Icon = programIcon;
        }
        tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        this.md5 = md5;
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

        bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        try
        {
            string strend = location.ToString().Substring(location.ToString().LastIndexOf('/')+1);

            string strstart = location.ToString().Substring(0,location.ToString().LastIndexOf('/')+1);

            strend = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strend);
            Uri locn = new Uri(strstart+strend);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(locn, this.tempFile); **//It fails here**
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No; this.Close(); }
    }
```

How can I pass the Uri to get the file that has the special character in it's name?

It worked when I changed the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a file address that contains special characters , you want to download the file depends on the deployment of server support  special character access .

For example , if IIS server don't support to access with special character, what changes have you made with url , the result is impossible.

The following is a solution about handling the filename contains special character , you could take reference with it.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CannotOpenAFileHavingSpecialCharactersInTheFilenameOnIIS.html